# Change the theme used for the user reset password page

Tags: 8, theming

Drupal 8 - I have the following issue:

- Administrator user creates an account for a user
- User gets a welcome email with password reset link
- Upon browsing the link and passing through the hint page, the user reaches [http://example.com/en/user/[USER-ID]/edit?pass-reset-token=[TOKEN]](http://example.com/en/user/%5BUSER-ID%5D/edit?pass-reset-token=%5BTOKEN%5D)

The problem is that the password reset page uses the administrator theme, while I need it uses the default site theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `RouteSubscriber` to do that but it will also affect your user edit form and render it with the default site theme since it uses the same route name. The RouteSubscriber can't alter a route based on a query string parameter such as `pass-reset-token`

**yourmodule/yourmodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  yourmodule.routesubscriber:
    class: Drupal\yourmodule\Routing\YourmoduleRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber, priority: 1 }
```

**yourmodule/src/Routing/YourmoduleRouteSubscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\yourmodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Custom route subscriber.
 */
class YourmoduleRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.edit_form')) {
      $options = $route->getOptions();
      $options['_custom_theme'] = 'yourthemename';
      $route->setOptions($options);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: OR use the [Switch page theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/switch_page_theme) module.

Comment: If you use a custom [theme negotiator](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158619) you can respond to the query string

Comment: Sounds good @Clive ! Your comment should be the answer in my opinion